# Line Graphic on QGIS Atlas

Tags: qgis, atlas, graphics

I have this attribute table, I would like plot on QGIS Atlas, a line graphic with last 7 days the fire events, from the day of the Atlas Page Name.

For example;

Atlas Page name is '2018-08-25', the graphic draw line of last 7 days automatically like the image below the table

[image]

Line graphic exemple

[image]

Comment: What have you tried and why wasnt the results as expected?

Comment: Give a look to [DataPlotly](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/DataPlotly/) plugin.